# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dropdownlistfor

I've done this EF MVC Application (Code First) with listing/editing/deleting functions. Everything works fine, but now I need to add two dropdown fields. Product has a category and a subcategory which needed to be edited. This is what I have so far:

Main class where ProductSubcategoryID is a foreign key

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ProductNumber { get; set; }
    public int? ProductSubcategoryID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectList> SelectedCat = new List<SelectList> {};
    public IEnumerable<SelectList> SelectedSubCat = new List<SelectList> {};
}

public class ProductCategory
{
    public int ProductCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProductSubcategory
{
    public int ProductSubcategoryID { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

}

On the Product controller class I have:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.SubcatSelection = new SelectList(dbSubcat.ProductSubcategories, "ProductSubcategoryID", "Name"); ;
    return View();
}
```

and on Edit:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductSubcategoryID)
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSubCat, ViewBag.SubcatSelection as SelectList, "ProductSubcategoryID", "Name");
```

The result:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SelectedSubCat'.

Comment: Because the value of `ViewBag.SubcatSelection` is `null` - probably because you submitted the form and returned the view without re-populaing the `ViewBag` property.

Comment: But you cannot bind a `<select>` to a property which is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (a `<select>` only posts back a single value) so you proeprty needs to be `public int SelectedSubCat { get; set; }` or you need to bind to property `ProductSubcategoryID` using `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProductSubcategoryID, ViewBag.SubcatSelection)` (and note the last parameter `"Name"` makes no sense at all)

Comment: I also recommend you read both the question and answer to [The ViewData item that has the key 'XXX' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) to understand how to do this correctly. And always use a view model - refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: Thank you for you detailed answer, it really helped me to get ahead. Now I have a working sample, I just changed my model class like this:

   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectedSubCat = new List<SelectListItem> { 
                new SelectListItem   { Text="Subcategory 1", Value = "1" },
                new SelectListItem   { Text="Subcategory 2", Value = "2" }
        };

Now the next step is that I want to read the Subcategories from database and not use static text. As above, I already have this ProductSubcategory class. What would yo recommend as easiest and practical way?